# XMonad does not start anything when used as window manager

Tags: installation, window-managers, xmonad

I wanted to use XMonad on Kubuntu. Therefore, I installed the packages given on the XMonad website (`xmonad`, `libghc-xmonad-dev`, `libghc-xmonad-contrib-dev`). When I try to use XMonad as a window manager (login screen), nothing happens as I click the login button (really nothing, so I just see the login screen with a cross-like cursor). I uninstalled the `apt`-packages and tried to use `stack`. However, whenever I use `stack install xmonad-contrib` (and `stack install xmonad` now... it worked once), I get an error message: `X11-xft-0.3.1: canonicalizePath: does not exist (No such file or directory)`.

Comment: I suppose the XMonad from packages should work well. It indeed shows you an empty screen on startup. I suppose you followed [the guided tour](http://xmonad.org/tour.html).

Comment: Is this really a programming question about Haskell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, XMonad *did* actually start. I was just very disappointed by the fact that I saw the login screen.